# Filtering PowerBI postal code data on format filters all values (Python/Power Query M)

Tags: python, database, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have been trying to filter my PowerBI data of postal codes on the right format (0000 AA or 0000AA). I have tried this both through Power Query M and python scripts, but both options cause all data to get filtered out, even the data that should be complying with the requirements.

The data is in a column in a big table, and contain in general 3 types of data: 1. actual postal codes in the right format, 2. null-values, 3. nonsense (abc, 123, etc).
[Part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNbvQ.png)

I have tried these pieces of code:

## Python

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pattern = r"\d{4}\s?[A-Z]{2}"

def validate_postal_code(postal_code):
    if re.match(pattern, str(postal_code)):
        return postal_code
    else:
        return None

dataset["OtherPostalCode"] = dataset["OtherPostalCode"].apply(validate_postal_code)

print(dataset)
```

## M

```
   #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Removed Other Columns", each[OtherPostalCode], 
        each if Value.Is(Text.Start([OtherPostalCode], 4), type number) & Value.Is(Text.End([OtherPostalCode], 2), type text) 
        then [OtherPostalCode]
        else Null.Type,
        Replacer.ReplaceValue, {OtherPostalCode})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
   #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue( #"Removed Other Columns",  each [OtherPostalCode],  each  try 
      if Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start([OtherPostalCode],4)), type number)
      and Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.End([OtherPostalCode],2)), type text)
      then [OtherPostalCode]
      else null otherwise null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"OtherPostalCode"})
```

sample full code

| OtherPostalCode |
| --- |
| 0000 AA |
| 0000AA |
| A0000AA |
| 00B0AAAA |
| AA0000 |
| 1111BB |
| 1111 BB |
| A211 BB |
| BB 1111 |

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue( Source,  each [OtherPostalCode],  each  try 
  if Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start([OtherPostalCode],4)), type number)
  and Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.End([OtherPostalCode],2)), type text)
  then [OtherPostalCode]
  else null otherwise null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"OtherPostalCode"})
in    #"Replaced Value"
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow these also have the same effect. It changes all values to "null", even the ones that should pass through without any issue. It sometimes leaves one postal code though, but I feel like that's more of a processing delay thing than an actual bug.

Comment: works for me.  Sample full set of data and code above along with image

Comment: Yeah, it's honestly probably my data being haunted at this point. Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it.

Comment: Update, it worked in the end!